# Dll version in 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

Im doing a project that needs to be converted from 2001 solution to 2010. I'm having problems with these dll's as this does not work anymore in 2010. Does anyone know what is the equaivalent of these dll's in vs 2010?

1) Microsoft.ApplicationBlocks.ExceptionManagement
2) Microsoft.Web.Services2

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

go through these links

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4.aspxhttp://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4.aspx

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/829026

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730294.aspx

This might be useful for you